# Warnings when validating AWS Elastic Transcoder HLS file using Apple's Media Stream Validator

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am currently transcoding my videos using `AWS Elastic Transcoder`. I create a job, and add outputs for the following quality presets:

- System Preset: HLS Audio - 64k
- System Preset: HLS 400k
- System Preset: HLS 1M
- System Preset: HLS 2M

I then create a master playlist called `index` and add these outputs/presets to it.

When the video is done transcoding, I'm using Apple's Media Stream Validator tool via terminal to validate the `index` file.

Here are the warnings that I am getting:

```
1) PROGRAM-ID has been deprecated and is no longer a valid attribute for #EXT-X-STREAM-INF
2) #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE should only be in master playlist
3) Unable to read video timestamps in track 1; this may be due to not having a key frame in this segment
4) Unable to read decode timestamps in track 1; this may be due to not having a key frame in this segment
```

I am not using any custom presets, only the ones that I listed above. These warnings happen both with videos recorded on the user's iPhone, and youtube videos that I have downloaded and converted to `.mov` files before converting them using `Elastic Transcoder`.

I know I can't be the only one experiencing these issues since they are defaults provided by `AWS Elastic Transcoder`.

I am worried that these warnings will prevent my iOS app from being accepted into the App Store.

Comment: Came back to leave a comment update. These warnings did not prevent our app from being approved for the App Store, but I still have not figured out how to get rid of them.

Comment: If you click the "presets" option in Elastic Transcoder console and then select a preset, you can "copy" it and make modifications. You may have some luck with validation if you play around with that.